# Negative integer request parameters not recognized when language is Arabic, other languages like english, german, french & chinese work fine

Tags: struts2, internationalization, struts2-interceptors

I have a struts2 web-application.

When I change the language to arabic, all query string urls, give un-certain results. I guess that's because `?` is considered to be some variable name and then it's not mapped properly to the target action by Struts2.

Although examples present on internet seems to work fine, so I guess this has something to do with my struts configuration.

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true"/>

    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="struts,global"/>
<!--    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="" />-->

    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.patternMatcher" value="regex" />
```

As long as the language is english, url like `http://localhost:8084/myaction?id=4` works perfectly fine and returns the required data but once the language is changed, that url bound action is never called, instead some other random action is being called.

**[UPDATE]**

Random actions are not called. Actually, the parameters don't get mapped and hence, due to validation checks in the action, the action returns INPUT. But the same url works when language is English i.e. parameters gets mapped perfectly and success is returned.

**[UPDATE 2]**

```
<interceptor-stack name="rememberMeStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="rememberme"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="store">
                    <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
                </interceptor-ref>
            </interceptor-stack>
```

Above is the interceptor stack I'm using.

**[UPDATE 3]**

```
http://localhost:8084/search?id=-1&...
```

Only parameters with value `-1` are giving OGNL exception `Error Setting Expression`, rest numbers seems to work fine.

**[UPDATE 4]**

I've tried using more languages and figured out that, it's not working ONLY for arabic languages. I guess it has something to do with their left-right alignment.

I also managed to write a small sample application, which demonstrates that only when language is arabic, the form submission gives error & with other any other language (english, chinese, french) it works fine.

I have also filed a bug on struts2 jira for this - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4241

Comment: It calls random actions?

Comment: for some urls, it's the default action for others, it's some different action then it was intended to.

Comment: ok, I've figured out, it's not random actions. Actually the parameters are not getting mapped and due to validations in the code, the action returns INPUT. But the same url works when language is english.

Comment: Do you follow the post-redirect-get pattern?

Comment: We'd need to know what validations are failing, and what's actually being sent by the browser.

Comment: there are OGNL exceptions : `OgnlValueStack.warn:64 - Error setting expression` and url being sent by browser is exactly the same as sent when the language is english. I've added my interceptor stack.

Comment: Also tell us how do you switch the locale.

Comment: `http://localhost:8084/index.action?request_locale=ar` - I switch the locale by calling this, and once called, it's managed automatically by Struts2 and hence, I don't send this request parameter again unless to change the language.

Comment: ? is a special character in regex and should be escaped accordingly.

Comment: yeah, I understand. But those URLs are working perfect in case of Locale English.

Comment: I've filed a bug for this - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4241

Comment: Are you on a totally UTF-8 chain ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly that means, but I've tried chinese, german & french too and they worked fine. Only arabic is giving issue.

Comment: Are you passing 1 or ۱ (AscII One or Arabic One)

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi please see update 3, I'm passing normal `-1` integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is very simple: Arabic is right to left script. So your `-1` is actually `1-` (and a String) you need to input `1-` to post negative integers.

Comment: So does that means, that once language is changed, it expects the request params to be of that language ? That means my normal english parameters will get reversed ? But that is not my intention. I just need to show menus & forms in 5 languages including arabic. And the form submit should work as expected in all languages without any additional coding for every separate language.

Comment: *form submit should work as expected* as expected for who? If you really want to i18n your app then you need to support rtl languages as well.

Comment: So the only solution is to code for every separate language ? Don't you think this is something to be handled by struts2-i18ln. It should be intelligent enough to figure out the language of the submitted request params and then de-serialize to action. Or may be I can write something in the JSP, so that struts2 can detect or know that the form is submitted in english language.

Comment: @coding_idiot: Conversions should happen considering current locale. If you don't want that then you could create some custom converter. Your question is answered (why and how). And definitely *NOT A BUG*.

Comment: But other parameters don't get reversed. They are accepted as it is. If only -ve integers are exception to this rule, then don't you think it can be considered a bug ?

Comment: @coding_idiot: What do you mean *reversed*? Nothing is getting reversed. Just conversion of dates and numbers are locale specific. Q: How app should know is it `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-dd-MM`, is it `-1` or `1-`? A: Locale.

Comment: but positive integers are read left-to-right, not right-to-left. Although it seems a valid explanation for the issue.

Comment: @coding_idiot: As I already told you the order of reading is not reversed. This is just a matter of where `-` is positioned. Take a look at `DecimalFormat` class. And if it is *valid explanation* accept/upvote this answer.

Comment: I've already upvoted :). The problem remains unsolved, as this explains the issue, but then how to solve it ? The way of converting all integers to string and then checking locale doesn't seem to be a good idea, there must be some other better way to do it.

Comment: @coding_idiot: What solution are you looking for? If you don't want that locale will be used in conversion then create custom converter.

Comment: can you please suggest some locale-specific-converter code ? I tried searching but couldn't find any.

Comment: [DefaultTypeConverter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.2.1.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/conversion/impl/DefaultTypeConverter.java?av=h#DefaultTypeConverter) - I couldn't find the locale setting anywhere.

Comment: @coding_idiot: Take a look at `NumberConverter`: https://github.com/apache/struts2/blob/STRUTS_2_3_15_3/xwork-core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/conversion/impl/NumberConverter.java.

Comment: great! I can simply edit one line `NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(getLocale(context));` from that, & then use
`java.lang.Number=MyNumberConverter` in properties file, right ?