# Freemarker casts negative integer in wrong way

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have found pretty interesting thing
Using java+spring+freemarker

From java controller I pass '-1' as Integer value.
From time to time in freemarker template after ${value} I am getting '1-' instead of '-1'
This happens randomly from time to time.

Any ideas why this happens? Freemarker bug?

Comment: Probably Locale specific. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19875848/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `${value?c}` that will format the number as a computer readable number.